# How do I redirect based on OS in PHP?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

I need a very simple script for QR code I will be implementing.

It should work like this:

1) User visits url

2) PHP script detects if user is using Android or iOS, or other operating system.

3) PHP script redirects Android to one url, iOS to other, other to the third url.

That's it!

Are there any ready scripts that can be used for this?

I know there are lots of redirects based on browsers, but I really need to detect the operating system to redirect user to Google Play or iTunes site.
Thank you!

Comment: You can use the UserAgentString to detect the OS as well as the browser.

Comment: You're restricted to whatever the browser decides to tell you; e.g. using `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` ... which of course can be totally spoofed but that's pretty much all you've got.

Comment: User agent is the way to go. The how is up to you. Can be Javascript, can be PHP can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
<?php
$user_agent = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");

if(strpos($user_agent, "Win") !== FALSE)
header("Location: /windows");
elseif(strpos($user_agent, "Mac") !== FALSE)
header("Location: /apple");
else
header("Location: /android");
```